# Modify form fields in FormWizard (Django 1.4)

Tags: django, django-formwizard

Consider the following classes:

models.py:

```
class Data(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField()
    checkbox_1 = models.BooleanField()
    checkbox_2 = models.BooleanField()
```

forms.py:

```
class Form1(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Data
        fields = ('first_name', 'checkbox_1',)

class Form2(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Data
        fields = ('checkbox_2',)
```

`Form1` is used in step 1 and `Form2` is used in step 2 of a `SessionWizardView`.

How could I disable `Form2.checkbox_2` in step 2 if the user checked `Form2.checkbox_1` in step 1?

I tried to accomplish this by overriding `get_form()` without success:

```
def get_form(self, step=None, data=None, files=None):
    form = super(MyWizard, self).get_form(step, data, files)
    if step == '1':
        form.fields['checkbox_2'].widget.attrs['disabled'] = 'disabled'
    return form
```

Please note that I intentionally did not check the value of `Form2.checkbox_1`. I tried to set the widget's attributes in any case.

Comment: Wizrd has separate forms for each step, so why do you need to change something based on the current step and not just provide a correct form for that step?

Comment: I updated the question to highlight the fact that I need to change a form field's attributes based on the values of the previous step.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this by overriding get_form_kwargs for the WizardView. It normally just returns an empty dictionary that get_form populates, so by overriding it to return a dictionary with the data you need prepopulated, you can pass kwargs to your form init.

```
def get_form_kwargs(self, step=None):
    kwargs = {}
    if step == '1':
        your_data = self.get_cleaned_data_for_step('0')['your_data']
        kwargs.update({'your_data': your_data,})
    return kwargs
```

Then, in your form **init** method you can just pop the kwarg off before calling super:

```
self.your_data = kwargs.pop('your_data', None)
```

and use that value to perform whatever logic you need to on the form.

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/contrib/formtools/form-wizard/#django.contrib.formtools.wizard.views.WizardView.get_form

Comment: I already tried that (and I updated my question accordingly).